# Error: Inner matrix dimensions must agree while scaling

Tags: matlab, transformation, spatial

I'm performing scaling operation on grid created. But the dimensions seem improper for the scaling the grid. Any ideas how to do it?
Code:

```
% plot grid
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-1:0.1:5, 0:0.1:1);
X = X(:);
Y = Y(:);
plot(X,Y,'b.');
xlabel('X'); 
ylabel('Y');
sx = 0.75;
sy = 0.6;
Tscale = [sx 0 0;
          0 sy 0;
          0 0 1];
Scale_val=Tscale*[X Y].';
X_Scale=Scale_val(1,:);
Y_Scale=Scale_val(2,:);
figure, plot(X_Scale, Y_Scale);
```

error:

```
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
Error in: Scale_val=Tscale*[X Y].';
```

Comment: What kind of scaling are you trying to implement using matrix multiplication? What is the expected output?

Comment: I am trying to perform spatial transformations using the grid created above.

Comment: You cannot multiply a [3x3] matrix with a [2xn] matrix. Just use `Tscale = [sx 0 ; 0 sy ];` and your code will run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Scale_val=Tscale*[X Y].';`

you were making 2 mistakes i think.
first of all your input coordinates are 2D with just X and Y, but you are trying to do a 3D transformation. second, the matrix multiplication format is not correct. this is what i think you were trying to do

```
Tscale = [sx 0 0;
          0 sy 0;
          0 0 1];
Scale_val=Tscale*[X'; Y'; zeros(1,length(X))];
X_Scale=Scale_val(1,:);
Y_Scale=Scale_val(2,:);
figure, plot(X_Scale, Y_Scale,'*');
```